# Shrink log file after configuring backups properly

Tags: sql-server, backup, transaction-log

I had a database that was working in FULL recovery mode but **never had transaction log backups done**.

The consequence of that was the fact that the log file kept growing and now its 10 GB in size.

**I configured scheduled backups for this database** (full + differential + log) and now log % space used is around 1%.

I want to shrink the 10GB file to a sensible size (maybe 200MB with autogrow 5 MB?).

How can I do it and what are the consequences of shrinking the file?

Comment: IMHO, 5MB autogrowth is not sensible. You should monitor your log growth using default trace and find a good value for autogrowth. (I will post the script later).

Comment: Great, Im looking forward to seeing the script. I have a question though. Why shouldn't I use autogrow if a log file is really being recreated after a differential backup?

Comment: @ŁukaszKastelik I don't think kin ment to say that autogrow is not sensible, but that 5MB is too small an increment. As for the script, there is a nice version [here](http://strictlysql.blogspot.be/2011/01/finding-last-database-growth-date-and.html) that I've used myself to monitor database growth.

Comment: @ŁukaszKastelik The whole log file is not being re-created. Where did you read that?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Maybe I don't understand it right but this is what I think it is like: when the DB is backed up regularly, the log file contains transaction history since the last full or differential backup. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: @ŁukaszKastelik Yes, but when you backup the log, it doesn't re-create the log file. It merely marks portions of the log file available for re-use, so that future transactions can be recorded in that space without having to grow the file and write into new space. Again, you said "log file is really being recreated" and I have no idea what you mean by that or how that ties into what is in the log with or without backups taking place.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. Is it possible to "recreate" the log file from scratch? Like when you create a database? I think it doesn't make sense to keep a 10GB log file when it can actually be 100 times smaller, right?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to shrink the 10GB file to a sensible size (maybe 200MB with autogrow 5 MB?).

IMHO, 5MB autogrowth is not sensible. You should monitor your log growth using default trace and find a good value for autogrowth.

Below script will help you monitor your Log (and Data file) autogrowths. Trend it over a week (or whatever suits your need). This will help you get a "near to best number" for your autogrowth setting.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#autogrowthTotal') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #autogrowthTotal;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#autogrowthTotal_Final') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #autogrowthTotal_Final;

DECLARE @filename NVARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @bc INT;
DECLARE @ec INT;
DECLARE @bfn VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @efn VARCHAR(10);

-- Get the name of the current default trace
SELECT @filename = CAST(value AS NVARCHAR(1000))
FROM ::fn_trace_getinfo(DEFAULT)
WHERE traceid = 1 AND property = 2;

-- rip apart file name into pieces
SET @filename = REVERSE(@filename);
SET @bc = CHARINDEX('.',@filename);
SET @ec = CHARINDEX('_',@filename)+1;
SET @efn = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@filename,1,@bc));
SET @bfn = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@filename,@ec,LEN(@filename)));

-- set filename without rollover number
SET @filename = @bfn + @efn

-- process all trace files
SELECT
  ftg.StartTime
  ,te.name AS EventName
,DB_NAME(ftg.databaseid) AS DatabaseName  
,ftg.[FileName] as LogicalFileName
,(ftg.IntegerData*8)/1024.0 AS GrowthMB
,(ftg.duration/1000)AS DurMS
,mf.physical_name AS PhysicalFileName
into #autogrowthTotal
FROM ::fn_trace_gettable(@filename, DEFAULT) AS ftg
INNER JOIN sys.trace_events AS te ON ftg.EventClass = te.trace_event_id 
join sys.master_files mf on (mf.database_id = ftg.databaseid) and (mf.name = ftg.[FileName]) 
WHERE (ftg.EventClass = 92  -- Data File Auto-grow
    OR ftg.EventClass = 93) -- Log File Auto-grow
ORDER BY ftg.StartTime

select count(1) as NoOfTimesEventFired
        , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), StartTime, 120) as StartTime
        , EventName
        , DatabaseName
        , [LogicalFileName]
        , PhysicalFileName
        , SUM(GrowthMB) as TotalGrowthMB
        , SUM(DurMS) as TotalDurationMS
into #autogrowthTotal_Final
from #autogrowthTotal
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), StartTime, 120),EventName,DatabaseName, [LogicalFileName], PhysicalFileName
having count(1) > 5 or SUM(DurMS)/1000 > 60 -- change this for finetuning....
order by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), StartTime, 120)

-- Report back the results
select * from #autogrowthTotal_Final
order by TotalDurationMS desc
-- optional Filters
-- where DatabaseName = ''
```

> Why shouldn't I use autogrow if a log file is really being recreated after a differential backup?

This is not true. When you take "Log Backups", SQL Server - for databases in **proper** FULL or BULK_LOGGED recovery models will truncate the transaction log i.e the portion of transaction log will be marked as "no longer needed" and will be overwritten.

Read up more on : [Misconceptions around the log and log backups: how to convince yourself](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/misconceptions-around-the-log-and-log-backups-how-to-convince-yourself/)  and [8 Steps to better Transaction Log throughput](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/8-steps-to-better-transaction-log-throughput/)

> I want to shrink the 10GB file to a sensible size (maybe 200MB with autogrow 5 MB?).
>   How can I do it and what are the consequences of shrinking the file?

You can use `DBCC SHRINKFILE(yourdb_log, 200);`. Remember to use `SHRINKFILE` and NOT `SHRINKDATABASE`.

I would suggest you to be PROACTIVE (monitor your log autogrowths and give a sensible value for autogrowth) rather being REACTIVE (frequently shrink log file, because you think that you will need disk space (or for whatever reasons)).

You should read up answers from [Mike Walsh](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/29830/8783) and [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48296/8783) for **[Why Does the Transaction Log Keep Growing or Run Out of Space?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/29829/8783)** to understand the consequences of shrinking log file.

Comment: Do you know a way to monitor your log to see how full it is over time?  Get a high water mark before they do the shrink at all?